# OpenCart 2.3 фильтр, скрыть часть в dropdown-menu

Tags: opencart, dropdown, фильтр

Подскажите как в коде сделать так чтобы отображалось только 3 пункта фильтра, а остальные скрыть в выпадающий dropdown-menu

```html
<div class="filters">
 <div class="row">
    <?php foreach ($filter_groups as $filter_group) { ?>
 
    <div class="opn col-sm-6" id="filter-group<?php echo $filter_group['filter_group_id']; ?>">

 <a><?php echo $filter_group['name']; ?></a>


   
     <ul class="nav navmenu" >
        <div class="p-t" >
   
 
        <?php foreach ($filter_group['filter'] as $filter) { ?>
  
<li class="filt_<?php echo $filter['filter_id']; ?> item" >
  <?php if (in_array($filter['filter_id'], $filter_category)) { ?>
 <input id="tag_<?php echo $filter['filter_id']; ?>" name="filter[]" value="<?php echo $filter['filter_id']; ?>" type="radio" data-checked="0" class="product-tags-j" checked="checked">
 <label for="tag_<?php echo $filter['filter_id']; ?>" class="custom-checkbox-label"> <span class="custom-checkbox-inner"></span><?php echo $filter['name']; ?></label>
            <?php } else { ?>
   <input id="tag_<?php echo $filter['filter_id']; ?>" name="filter[]" value="<?php echo $filter['filter_id']; ?>" type="radio" data-checked="0" class="product-tags-j" >
            <label for="tag_<?php echo $filter['filter_id']; ?>" class="custom-checkbox-label"> <span class="custom-checkbox-inner"></span><?php echo $filter['name']; ?></label>
            <?php } ?> 
</li> 


 
  <?php } ?>      
  
 

<li class="font-base dropdown">
  <a role="button" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="p-0 border-n"> показать все <span class="caret"></span> </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu p-t-2">
  
  </ul>
  </li>
  
  </div>

  </ul>
 
   

  </div>
  
    <?php } ?>
 
 
  </div>
  
  <!--div class="poisk2">
    <button type="button" id="button-filter" class="btn btn-primary"><?php echo $button_filter; ?></button>
  </div-->
   </div>

<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$('input[name^=\'filter\']').on('click', function() {
 filter = [];

 $('input[name^=\'filter\']:checked').each(function(element) {
  filter.push(this.value);
 });

 location = '<?php echo $action; ?>&filter=' + filter.join(',');
});
//--></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

В общем виде, но, думаю, адаптировать не составит труда:

```js
$('.more-options').on('click', function (el) {
  let $li = $(this).parent().find('ul.list li.filter-item');
  $li.toggleClass('active');
  $(this).html(($li.hasClass('active')) ? 'less options' : 'more options');
})
```

```css
.list li{list-style:none;}
.list li:nth-child(n+4){display:none}
.list li.active{display:block}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="filter-option">
  <p>Filter 1</p>
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="filter-item">option 1</li>
    <li class="filter-item">option 2</li>
    <li class="filter-item">option 3</li>
    <li class="filter-item">option 4</li>
    <li class="filter-item">option 5</li>
    <li class="filter-item">option 6</li>
  </ul>
  <span class="more-options">more options</span>
</div>
```